# Preg Replace Question PHP

Tags: php

I have a url, http://www.jdocy.com/click-42343-32422

I want to replace the 42343 section of the url with php's preg_replace function.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to transform www.jdocy.com/42343-32422 to www.jdocy.com/32422? If so, you would use backreferences, something like:

```
 $url = preg_replace('/^(.+/)[0-9]+-([0-9]+)$/', '$1$2', $url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rep = '\1' + addslashes(111111) + '-\3';
$url = preg_replace('#(/)([\d]+)-([\d]+)#', $rep, $url);
```

Where 111111 is what you want to add.  Addslashes is necessary to prevent accidentally including a backreference (\1, \2, \3)...

Edit: Fix missing quote

Comment: Just watch the missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = preg_replace('`(?<=\.com/click-)\d+`i', 'replacement text', $url);
```

Use a [look-behind](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#11) and you don't need to re-insert any text.

Comment: whoops, i just realized the link is of the form "http://www.jdocy.com/click-42343-32422" , how can I modify your code to fit this form instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = preg_replace('/^(.+/)[0-9]+-([0-9]+)$/', '$1$2', $url)
```

*[spam edited out]*